# Asterisk ignoring sip_domain part of URI

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip, dial

I am using Asterisk version 11.5. My problem is the following: I literally cannot make any outbound call. That's because, whatever I dial in any client, the sip_domain part gets ignored, it is interpreted as an internal asterisk domain call:

```
endpoint@sip_domain
```

It doesn't matter what I dial, even if I dial endpoint@blablablabla the call gets redirected to my asterisk server. What might it be? If you need any other info, tell me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT - sip.conf:**

```
[general]
context=from-sip
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=h264
allow=h263
allow=t140
rtcachefriends=yes
rtupdate=yes
srvlookup=yes
videosupport=yes
textsupport=yes
directmedia=no
icesuport=true
;nat=force_rport,comedia
accept_outofcall_message=yes
outofcall_message_context=sip-messaging
auth_message_requests=yes
```

**EDIT - sip debug logs**

In the following files you can find debug logs of a successful call (external to internal) and a failed call (internal to external): http://sdrv.ms/1axKGli .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your concealed sip.conf it would beneficial to assist you. Also, connect to asterisk in verbose mode `asterisk -vvvvr` or enable sip debugging `sip set debug on` might tell you a bit more about the problem. Also with this type of question it would help if you posted the SIP header information as well -

Try setting `allowexternaldomains=yes`

**note:** performing a dig on the domain t-meeting.se for the SRV record yields no answer, have you tried calling another number on a sip server that supports SRV lookup?

It looks like your dialplan needs some modification. I would consider taking a look at this [link](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Patterns). Towards the bottom they define a macro that can accomplish what you are looking for. However in short you need something like the following in
**extensions.conf**. You will probably need to alter this to work with realtime but this is the jist:

```
exten => _.,n,Macro(uri-dial,${EXTEN}@${SIPDOMAIN})
exten => _.,n,HangUp()

[macro-uri-dial]
exten => s,n,NoOp(Calling as SIP address: ${ARG1})
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/${ARG1},60)
```

Comment: Added more details to question.

Comment: Sorry, what about your dialplan? Could you post relevant lines from that as well? I will see what I can find!

Comment: Also, is this your entire sip.conf? You do not have outboundproxy set or anything else? Also I would like to see even more information, having the relevant extensions from extensions.conf would also be useful. There are a lot of variables that need to be considered.

Comment: Regarding your note: even if i call a random number like this: 01@blablablablabla.com , the message is the same: extension not found in context... The same with an ekiga.net account. I'll add a link to my sample extensions.conf and extensions table in db (i am using realtime)

Comment: Skydrive link has updated data with extensions.conf and extension.table (table data).

Comment: No problem! I am glad you got it working, fun isn't it !?